# Work done to compress a liquid in container

Tags: pressure, integration, volume

Into a compressed container containing water with pressure **p** and volume **V** we want to pump additional water. What is the work done? Unlike in the ideal gas, the work cannot be simply found out using integration. I anticipate there will be a bulk modulus required. I appreciate all help!

Comment: If the container is already full, water is essentially incompressible, so be prepared to spend a _lot_ of energy and put _tons_ of stress on the container walls.

Comment: I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Unfortunately, [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633) questions are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer conceptual questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem? Also mention any thoughts you currently have about the solution, and your assessment of their usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can approximate this as a process where the existing volume, say $V_0$, is reduced to $V_1$, where:

$\Delta V=V_0-V_1$

is the volume of water you want to add.

First we compress $V_0$ to $V_1$, to make room for water to be added. During the compression pressure will increase from $p_0$ to $p_1$ and the compression requires work as per your question.

The work done due this compression is:

$$\int_0^W\text{d}W=\int_{V_0}^{V_1}p(V)\text{d}V\tag{1}$$

The [Bulk Modulus Elasticity](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/bulk-modulus-elasticity-d_585.html) $K$ is defined as:

$$K=V_0\frac{p_1-p_0}{V_1-V_0}$$

Or more generally:

$$K=V_0\frac{p(V)-p_0}{V-V_0}$$
So:

$$p(V)=\frac{K(V-V_0)}{V_0}+p_0\tag{2}$$

With $(2)$ into $(1)$:

$$W=\int_{V_0}^{V_1}\Big(\frac{K(V-V_0)}{V_0}+p_0\Big)\text{d}V\tag{3}$$

$$W=\Big[\frac{KV^2}{2V_0}-KV_0V+p_0V\Big]_{V_0}^{V_1}$$

$$\boxed{W=\frac{KV_1^2}{2V_0}-\frac{KV_0}{2}+K(V_0-V_1)-p_0(V_0-V_1)}$$

For water, $K$ is about $2.15\times 10^9\mathrm{Pa}$.

Comment: This is assuming the container is infinitely stiff , which is probably a very fair approximation in a real application.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: That´s what I have forgotten to mention, you did it is if you had read my mind.

Comment: Hello @Gert, the link for bulk modulus that you gave writes it as the negative of what you've written. Your Eq. (2) suggests that $V-V_0 < 0$ implies $P(V) < P_0$, and I think it should be the other way around. Is the sign of $K$ as you gave wrong?